# Trouble using list of slot variables?

Tags: slot

When I run this code:

```
S={a,b};
G=Subsets[S];
R=Table[SymmetricDifference[G[[i]],G[[j]]],{i,1,Length@G},{j,1,Length@G}];
TableForm[R/.({#1->1,#2->2,#3->3,#4->4}&@@G)]
```

It works as desired, ie: It outputs:

> [image: >[![enter image description here][1]][1]]

But when I do this with T being a list with the Slot[i] -> i:

```
S={a,b};
G=Subsets[S];
R=Table[SymmetricDifference[G[[i]],G[[j]]],{i,1,Length@G},{j,1,Length@G}];
T=Table[Slot[i]->i,{i,Length@G}];
TableForm[R/.(T&@@G)]
```

I get:

> [image]

I don't understand why this change of behavior happens. Can you help me?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2414/1871 BTW, you've posted a wrong screenshot for the first output.

Comment: [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) is [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html). Use `TableForm[R /. (Evaluate[T] & @@ G)]`.

Comment: Simpler example showing the issue: `expr = #;
{expr &@aaaaaa, Evaluate[expr] &@aaaaa}`

Comment: I know you didn't ask, but you might find this to be a bit cleaner, generalizable to different-sized lists, and ultimately easier to understand: `TableForm[Map[First@FirstPosition[G, #] &, R, {2}]]`. Or, since we know the elements of `G` are unique, `TableForm[Map[First@Position[G, #] &, R, {2}]]`. When I saw `{#1 -> 1, #2 -> 2, #3 -> 3, #4 -> 4} & @@ G`, I asked myself "isn't that just mapping each element to its position?".

Comment: @lericr I'm always open to tips and suggestions. I learn a lot with you guys!